# Trouble Implementing Google Play Sign in with app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-signin

I have followed the directions on the google developer site, but can not get it right...

Here are my relevant code snippets from my MainActivity:

imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;
```

implementations:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{ ...}
```

Variables:

```
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;



SharedPreferences stats;
SharedPreferences achievements;
SharedPreferences.Editor stat_editor;
SharedPreferences.Editor achievement_editor;
```

This is instantiated `onCreate()`

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
```

Activity cycle methods:

```
    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Implemented methods:

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    //hide sign in  button
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Attempt to reconnect
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // already resolving
        return;
    }

    // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
        mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."
        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }

    // Put code here to display the sign-in button
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
            // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
            // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
            // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                    requestCode, resultCode, R.string.sign_in_failed);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I currently do not have a sign in button, just trying to have the user auto-prompted to sign in.

The app crashes a second after it pops up.

I think may be missing a meta tag or permission? Currently this is all I have.

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

The other possibility is an improper set up on the google developer console. What all do I need to do to get this thing to connect?! I am lost!! Thanks.

```
08-06 17:17:23.910  30903-30939/? E/HTTPMetricsTransport﹕ transmit - MissingCredentialsException while transmitting;
amazon.communication.MissingCredentialsException: Static Credential is unavailable.
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.StaticCredentialRequestSigner.signRequest(StaticCredentialRequestSigner.java:44)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.MetricsHttpRequestSigner.signRequest(MetricsHttpRequestSigner.java:54)
        at amazon.communication.srr.HttpClientSrrManager.makeRequestSync(HttpClientSrrManager.java:190)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.HTTPMetricsTransport.makeRequest(HTTPMetricsTransport.java:286)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.HTTPMetricsTransport.attemptToTransmit(HTTPMetricsTransport.java:230)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.HTTPMetricsTransport.attemptToTransmit(HTTPMetricsTransport.java:235)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.transport.HTTPMetricsTransport.transmit(HTTPMetricsTransport.java:202)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.batch.transmitter.BatchTransmitter$QueuePusher.sendBatches(BatchTransmitter.java:161)
        at com.amazon.client.metrics.batch.transmitter.BatchTransmitter$QueuePusher.run(BatchTransmitter.java:127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Also, I read something about generating a client ID and downloading a JSON file and importing it into your project, maybe this could be the problem? I generated a client ID, but have not included any JSON file, how would I do that?

**UPDATE**

I changed to:

```
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();
```

Removing these two lines that I originally had:

```
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
```

The app no longer crashes when it loads, but there is still no attempt to connect, or no google sign in window that pops up.

Comment: Hey Mike, please add the stack trace from logcat as you're getting a crash

Comment: @ataulm I added the first error I encounter. There are many more that follow. All of which start with : `08-06 17:17:26.080  29885-31047/? E/LocalFingerprints﹕ cannot compute fingerprint for: content://media/external/video/media/5021`

Comment: Did you follow the official tutorial? It's very important to set up everything correctly in the google dev console as well. Btw, you can take a look at my sample app if you like https://github.com/joaocsousa/OAuth, just remember to update the google dev console with the apropriate package name and SHA1.

Comment: @JoaoSousa Yes, I submitted my SHA1 which I got from the debug.keystore utility. I also entered the package name on the dev console which I got from my android manifest. The only thing I was confused about was getting the configuration file which said: "Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/ or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project. Open the Android Studio Terminal pane:"

Comment: Did you export the apk file or did you use the "run" option with your emulator/phone? If you export a signed apk you need to setup with your app's keystore SHA1, otherwise you're right using the right key for debug!

Comment: Also, if you want to try only with Plus API use also `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` to request the login. And maybe it will solve all your issues. On the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you no longer have the errors you were complaining about, and the only thing missing is the step to connect. Try to add:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
} else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
    mSignInClicked = true;
    // uncomment the next line if you have this method.
    // resolveSignInError();
}
```

to your `onResume`.

--EDIT--

I see that you get the error `API_UNAVAILABLE`. I think you haven't activated the Google+ API. Go to [the official Google tutorial, Step 1](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started). Pay close attention to the step 4 and make sure you enable the Google+ API. You'll need to see something like in this picture.

[image].

Notice the "Disable API" button. That means the API is enabled for sure.

One more thing that might be the key to your problem here. Try to add this permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: No, did not work. Just to make sure I am understanding this implementation correctly.. A window should automatically pop up right? Or do I need to MAKE that window pop up? Also, I found this in my logcat : `08-06 18:19:41.223   32288-1919/? E/MDM﹕ [26084] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}`